# How to handle database setup/cleanhup in benchmark.net?

Tags: c#, .net, database, benchmarking, benchmarkdotnet

I want to benchmark different "INSERT" implementations into a database (EF, Dapper, etc) but don't know how and where to handle the SETUP and CLEANUP of the database.

There is a GlobalSetup and an IterationSetup method in Benchmark.net, but in the documentation it is said that CPU intensive operations can skew the results. This confused me, because I don't care about the Setup/Cleanup stuff w.r.t runtime (I only care about the specific INSERT function, which expects a correct database).

How do I handle Setup/Cleanup of a database for functions that I want to benchmark with benchmark.net?

Comment: Does you database have primary keys?  If a primary key exist for an object INSERT will not work since the key exists.  You would need to use UPDATE of delete the keys before adding again.

Comment: yes they have primary keys. That is the reason why I need to database to be "Initialized" correctly everytime my benchmarked function is called.

Comment: I usually recommend that you create a database for testing which you can copy and use a copy for each test so you always start with the same data.

Comment: In general I understand that. I was hoping to be able to use the "Setup" functions in Benchmark.NET. But they seem to "skew" the results accotding to some tutorials I read. 
Where would I call the "Copy" function of the Test-Database?

Comment: What type of database?  SQL Server?  The MDF file is the database.  You can deattach from Server and then make copies in windows.  Then reattach the copies.  The copies can be attached with a different name.

Comment: Lets say, SQL Server. But I dont think that is the point. I am trying to figure out when and where to do all of the setup/init process when using Benchmarlk.NET. When do I call all of that?

Comment: See following.  Read FAQ. The database is part of the c# project even though it may be on the SQL Server. https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet/blob/master/docs/articles/guides/getting-started.md?force_isolation=true  and https://www.codemag.com/Article/2209061/Benchmarking-.NET-6-Applications-Using-BenchmarkDotNet-A-Deep-Dive?force_isolation=true

Comment: https://andreyakinshin.github.io/bdn-docs-wip/articles/features/setup-and-cleanup.html